# Illegal string offset 'type'

Tags: php

I have this error on this code :
Any idea ?
Illegal string offset 'type'

```
    foreach ($_POST['product_option'] as $product_option) {

      var_dump( $product_option['type']);
      $type =  $product_option['type'];

      if ($type == 'file') {
        $value_type = 'file';
      } elseif ($type == 'textarea') {
        $value_type = 'textarea';
      } else {
        $value_type = $type;
      }
```

}

result of `var_dump($product_option['type'])` :

```
Save.php:61:string 'radio' (length=5)
Save.php:61:string 'select' (length=6)
Save.php:61:string 'checkbox' (length=8)
Save.php:61:string 'textarea' (length=8)
```

Element of result of `$product_option`

> array (size=3)
>             'option_id' => string '43' (length=2)
>             'type' => string 'radio' (length=5)
>
> ```
> Save.php:60:
>     array (size=2)
>       'option_id' => string '44' (length=2)
>       'type' => string 'select' (length=6)
> Save.php:60:
>     array (size=2)
>       'option_id' => string '47' (length=2)
>       'type' => string 'checkbox' (length=8)
>
> Save.php:60:
>     array (size=2)
>       'option_id' => string '55' (length=2)
>       'type' => string 'file' (length=4)
> ```

Comment: This can not be $_POST['product_option']['type'] true. once update var_dump of $_POST

Answer (score 1):

You are currently not working with the foreach iteration as `$_POST['product_option'][x]`. has x number of elements which all contain a type element.

Change

```
$type = $_POST['product_option']['type'];
```

to

```
 $type = $product_option['type'];
```

Comment: It was an error follow to test I use $product_option['type'] but I havet the same error : change the code above

Comment: possibly not every $_POST['product_option'] item has an index of type? Run a var_dump() of $_POST and edit the question with those results

Comment: the result of var_dump($product_option['type']) is above

Comment: that's not what i asked for, i asked for a var_dump of $_POST['product_option']